# Google Analytics / Tag Manager Internal Site Search API

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I need to track the site search query terms for an internal site search I have placed on the website.

My plan is to enable the Site Search settings within Google Analytics.

However my site search page does not use the standard query string variables that the site search uses to track queries. Instead my site search page is updated through AJAX. Is there an API call I can do to send the query and the category to the Google Site Search tracking.

Also I need to track the username of the user doing the search (this is behind a login so all users will be logged in). Is there a way I can send some sort of meta data to include the username?

Let me know if the Site Search Tracking is not the correct way to approach this if I should be using some other sort of tools such as event tracking.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC: 
Please see the sample code below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Search/',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { search_phrase: 
       search_phrase
},
success: function(data) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may send a 'virtual' pageview in success calllback composint the suitable value instead of an actual document location like

```
success: function(data) { 
  ga('send', {
    hitType: 'pageview',
    page: location.origin + 'search?q=' + search_phrase
  });
}
```

If you're using GTM you may push the search phrase to dataLayer and then fire Google Analytics Tag with owerwritten location field for this custom event:

```
success: function(data) { 
  dataLayer.push({
    event: 'internal search', // allows you to set up custom event
    search_phrase: search_phrase
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm using GTM, can I use the first block of code? Will it still work?

Comment: the first block of code is supposed to be used as a success callback to ajax request. It has nothing to do with GTM and is supposed to work with oldfashioned analytics.js implementation. If you're using GTM consider using the second approach with dataLayer.push

Comment: I ended up getting it to work using the GTM code like so: searchQuery = query.toLowerCase(); virtualPage = '/searchTracking?s=' + searchQuery;
                        dataLayer.push({'event': 'internal-search'}); I then created an interal search event in GTM named "internal-search". virtualPage was setup as a GTM Javascript Variable which then mapped to PageView.